# Create Fulltext index on a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am going to create a full text index on a view but the unique index combo box in full text indexing wizard is disabled and "A unique column must be defined on this table/view" message is displayed. although i created a composite unique index on that view.

Any clue would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full text indexes have a few restrictions, I wrote a quick [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnsoldevs/archive/2011/09/13/quick-sql-tips-indexed-views.aspx) that shows the TSQL syntax so you can see if you an error message and listed the restrictions that may be causing you problems.